# XSLT increment value of attribute keeping length of the value same

Tags: xml, xslt, auto-increment

It would seem like a duplicate question but its not (I have searched all over SO and couldn't find an answer).

So I have an XSLT which needs to be transformed into XML and essentially there is an attribute where the value has to be incremented, however we have been given a set format for the value where the last part increments but the length of the value cannot exceed 18 characters, heres a working example of what I have :

**XSLT :**

```
<xsl:for-each select="Transactions/Transaction">
<Interaction
SourceCode="SRC12799"
ExternalID="ERHYDM000000000{position()}">
 </Interaction>
</xsl:for-each>
```

OUTPUT :

```
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000001">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000002">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000003">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000004">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000005">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000006">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000007">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000008">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000009">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM00000000010"> <!-- Issue with length -->
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT (Length of ExternalID should remain the same) :**

```
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000001">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000002">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000003">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000004">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000005">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000006">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000007">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000008">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000009">
<Interaction SourceCode="SRC12799" ExternalID="ERHYDM0000000010"> <!-- This is the corrected  part (Same will happen for 100s 10000s and so on) -->
```

How do I keep the length of the value constant while incrementing the value ?

Comment: The required logic is not entirely clear. You already have 15 characters; once you reach 999, something must be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will provide the required formatting. It will work from `001` to `999` i.e. for `999 <Transaction>` nodes.

```
<xsl:variable name="srcCd" select="'SRC12799'" />
<xsl:variable name="extIdPfx" select="'ERHYDM000000000'" />
<xsl:for-each select="Transactions/Transaction">
    <xsl:variable name="extId" select="concat($extIdPfx, format-number(position(),'000'))" />
    <Interaction>
        <xsl:attribute name="SourceCode">
            <xsl:value-of select="$srcCd" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="ExternalID">
            <xsl:value-of select="$extId" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </Interaction>
</xsl:for-each>
```